AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'show_privileges'
Python is not recognizing my def show_privileges function
class User:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, login_attempts, email, location):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.login_attempts = login_attempts
        self.email = email
        self.location = location

    def describe_user(self):
        print(f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}")
        print(f"You have {self.login_attempts} login attempts")
        print(f"{self.email}")
        print(f"{self.location}")

    def greet_user(self):
        print(f"Hi {self.first_name} {self.last_name} ")

    def location_user(self):
        print(f"Hi {self.first_name},you are from London, South")

    def increment_login_attempts(self, login):
        self.login_attempts = + login

class Admin(User):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, login_attempts, email, location):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, login_attempts, email, location)
        self.privileges = []

    def show_privileges(self):
        print("\nPrivileges:")
        for priviledge in self.privileges:
            print(f"- {priviledge}")

admin = User("Fred", "Osei", "6", "fred@fredas.com", "London")
fred = User("John", "Chris", "8", "johnchris@life.com", "Manchester")
admin.describe_user()

admin.privileges = ["Can Post", "Can Create Accounts", "Can Delete Account"]
admin.show_privileges()

Im confused as to why it's not recognizing the show_privileges functions. I believe I have done everything right

I think you meant admin = Admin("Fred", ..... ? Right now you've defined your admin with the User class, which doesn't (and perhaps shouldn't!) have the show_privileges function.

Alternatively, adding a privileges attribute to admin does not "promote" it to an Admin. That is, all Admin instances have a privileges attribute; however, not all instances of User that have a privileges attribute are also Admin attributes.

Are the first 5 functions supposed to be methods of the User class?

@Barmar yeah that's correct

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The way your code is currently structured, a User object does not have a method called show_privileges. Since you initialized admin as a User, it won't have its own show_privileges method even though it has a list of privileges.
One option is to make admin an Admin instead of a User:
admin = Admin("Fred", "Osei", "6", "fred@fredas.com", "London")

Another is to nix the Admin class entirely and just give each User its own (potentially-empty) list of privileges. This will make it easier to promote base users, which is something you seem to be interested in:
class User:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, login_attempts, email, location):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.login_attempts = login_attempts
        self.email = email
        self.location = location
        self.privileges = [] # Move this from Admin to User
    
    def describe_user(self):
        print(f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}")
        print(f"You have {self.login_attempts} login attempts")
        print(f"{self.email}")
        print(f"{self.location}")
    
    def greet_user(self):
        print(f"Hi {self.first_name} {self.last_name} ")
    
    def location_user(self):
        print(f"Hi {self.first_name},you are from London, South")
    
    def increment_login_attempts(self, login):
        self.login_attempts = + login

    def show_privileges(self): # Move this from Admin to User as well
        print("\nPrivileges:")
        for priviledge in self.privileges:
            print(f"- {priviledge}")

admin = User("Fred", "Osei", "6", "fred@fredas.com", "London")
fred = User("John", "Chris", "8", "johnchris@life.com", "Manchester")
admin.describe_user()

admin.privileges = ["Can Post", "Can Create Accounts", "Can Delete Account"]
admin.show_privileges()

These are just two solutions; there are many others that could work equally well or better depending on your use case.
